# bash getopts behavior different in while loop vs commandline

Tags: bash, shell

Commandline

```
$ getopts ":mnopq:rs" Option -q
$ echo $Option 
?
$ echo $OPTARG
```

Given

```
$ cat getopt.sh 
#!/bin/bash

echo '$@' is $@
while getopts ":mnopq:rs" Option
do
  echo Option is  $Option  
  echo OPTARG is $OPTARG  
  case $Option in
    m     ) echo "Scenario #1: option -m-   [OPTIND=${OPTIND}]";;
    n | o ) echo "Scenario #2: option -$Option-   [OPTIND=${OPTIND}]";;
    p     ) echo "Scenario #3: option -p-   [OPTIND=${OPTIND}]";;
    q     ) echo "Scenario #4: option -q-\
                  with argument \"$OPTARG\"   [OPTIND=${OPTIND}]";;
    #  Note that option 'q' must have an associated argument,
    #+ otherwise it falls through to the default.
    r | s ) echo "Scenario #5: option -$Option-";;
    *     ) echo "Unimplemented option chosen.";;   # Default.
  esac
done
```

I get

Script

```
$ ./getopt.sh -q
$@ is -q
Option is :
OPTARG is q
Unimplemented option chosen.
```

Why is there a difference in output between Commandline and Script ?

Comment: I can't reproduce it in bash 3.2.57 or 4.2.37.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you run the "Commandline" test multiple times in the same shell? `getopts` uses the variable `OPTIND` to keep track of where it is in the argument list, so it doesn't just process the same option over and over. As a result, if you run the test multiple times it'll skip over what it processed last time. In your case, I suspect this is making it think it's at the end of the argument list (in which case it'll have an exit status of 1). Here's an excerpt from the bash man page:

> [...] Each time it is invoked, `getopts` places [...] the index
>   of the next argument to be processed into the variable `OPTIND`. `OPTIND`
>   is initialized to 1 each time the shell or a shell script is invoked.
>   [...] The shell does not reset `OPTIND` automatically; it
>   must be manually reset between multiple calls to `getopts` within the
>   same shell invocation if a new set of parameters is to be used.

Here's an example:

```
$ getopts ":mnopq:rs" Option -q
$ echo "status=$?, Option='$Option', OPTARG='$OPTARG', OPTIND=$OPTIND"
status=0, Option=':', OPTARG='q', OPTIND=2
$
$ getopts ":mnopq:rs" Option -q
$ echo "status=$?, Option='$Option', OPTARG='$OPTARG', OPTIND=$OPTIND"
status=1, Option='?', OPTARG='', OPTIND=2
$
$ unset OPTIND
$ getopts ":mnopq:rs" Option -q
$ echo "status=$?, Option='$Option', OPTARG='$OPTARG', OPTIND=$OPTIND"
status=0, Option=':', OPTARG='q', OPTIND=2
```

The first time it does what you expect. The second time it indicates it's out of options to process, which matches what you're seeing. The third time `OPTIND` has been unset, so it defaults back to the beginning of the argument list.